# Remove special characters from a column in a pipe delimiter file - Generic

Tags: text-processing

I need to create a generic script to remove special characters `[|!@#$%^&*\]` from a particular column in a pipe delimited file.

For example, I have pipe (`|`) delimited files and I have a column 'Review Comments' common to all the files. I need to remove all the special character given above from the Review comments column.

I am able to delete special character from a file using `sed` command but I am not able to create a generic script.

Comment: Is "Review Comments" always in the same position, ie. the same column number?

Comment: No, Review Comments will not be in the same position. It will be in different position for different files

Comment: beware: in a pipe-delimited file, none of your field values can contain the pipe character, unless the field is quoted and you are using a proper CSV parser.

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` script searches for a field containing only "Review Comments" in first line, then removes all special characters from that field in all the remaining lines.

```
BEGIN {
    FS="|"
    OFS="|"
}
FNR==1 { 
    for ( N=1 ; N<=NF ; N++ ) { 
        if ( $N ~ /^Review Comments$/ )
            revcol=N
    }
}
FNR>1 {
    gsub("[!@#$%^&*\\\\]","",$revcol) 
}
{ print }
```

Comment: I have intentionally omitted "|" from the list of characters to remove, but including it will make no difference, because it's the field-separator/delimiter.